# Don't force redirect to the language folder

Tags: php, redirect

I have a PHP script who redirect the client to the language folder based on the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` variable that retrieves the language of the preferred browser

**Folder hierarchy :**

```
-> exemple.ru (main site)
     -> exemple.ru/fr/
     -> exemple.ru/en/
     -> exemple.ru/es/
     -> ...
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
   $lc = "";
   if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
       $lc = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
   }
   if($lc == "ru"){
       header("location: /index.php");
       exit();
   } else if($lc == "fr"){
       header("location: ".$lc."");
       exit();
   } else if($lc == "en"){
       header("location: ".$lc."");
       exit();
   } else if($lc == "es"){
       header("location: ".$lc."");
       exit();
   } else {
       header("location: /index.php");
?>
```

The redirect works well, each clients is redirected to the corect folder based on their navigator prefered languages.

What I would like now is that, if the client is FR and that he want to see the RU version, he may enter to the exemple.com location which contain the main language (RU) and not to be forced to be in his language folder.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Resolved]**

1) I defined my folder hierarchy like that :

```
-> root ( exemple.tld - In my case exemple.ru )
    -> /en/    ( which contain the site in en version )
    -> /fr/    ( fr version )
```

2) Create a file named `language.php` and put this code :

```
session_start(); // Start the Session
if (isset($_GET['language'])) {
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['language'];
}

if (isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
    $lc = $_SESSION['language'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    $lc = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
}

if($lc == "ru"){
    header("location: http://exemple.ru/");
    exit();
} else if($lc == "fr"){
    header("location: ".$lc.""); // Will redirect to /en/ folder
    exit();
} else if($lc == "en"){
    header("location: ".$lc.""); // Will redirect to /fr/ folder
    exit();
}
```

3) Create the form in each index.php page `( root/index.php, /en/index.php, /fr/index.php )`

-- For the root site I have this form

```
<form action="language.php" method="get">
    <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="ru">RU</option>
        <option value="en">EN</option>
        <option value="fr">FR</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

-- For the /en/ site this form

```
<form action="language.php" method="get">
    <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="EN">EN</option>
        <option value="FR">FR</option>
        <option value="RU">RU</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

-- For the /en/ site this form

```
<form action="language.php" method="get">
    <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="FR">FR</option>
        <option value="EN">EN</option>
        <option value="RU">RU</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

4) Now to redirect each clients to the correct folder based on their navigator preferred languages or session if it has been defined when they arrive to exemple.ru/. You must put this code in the beginning of the main root index.php before the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag :

```
<?php
session_start(); // Require

if (isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
    $lc = $_SESSION['language'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    $lc = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
}

if($lc == "fr"){
    header("location: ".$lc.""); 
    exit();
} else if($lc == "en"){
    header("location: ".$lc.""); 
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
.... CODE HTML
```

Hope these help

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to set a session variable for that user, so if they explicitly choose a language, it overrides the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header.

So you might have a dropdown for the language, and when they change it you set the session:

```
session_start(); // if you haven't already
if (isset($_GET['language'])) {
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['language'];
}
```

Then when setting the language you might have

```
if (isset($_SESSION['language'])) {
    $lc = $_SESSION['language'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    $lc = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you John C for you attention and sorry butI do not understand very well what do you mean, my level in php is not so good as well so I will appreciate if you can detail more.

If I understand, I should create a form like that : 

     <form name='language' action='language.php' method='get'>
     <select id="lang-select" name="lang-select"  onchange="this.form.submit();">
     <option value="fr">fr</option>
     <option value="en">en </option> 
     <option value="es">es </option>                  
     </select>
    </form>


then create a file named language.php and put your php code ?

Comment: That looks about right @colapsnux - you're doing pretty well with it!